# How do I get hotkey SIGINT signal back in the goland terminal on macos?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland, sigint

I stopped sending SIGINT to the process in the terminal on mac os. Previously, when I pressed the keyboard shortcut `control + C`, I ended the process in the terminal. And now I've stopped

How do I get it back?

Comment: You can invoke this process with sudo privileges, GoLand changed that behavior in 2022.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5982/Debugger-kills-instead-of-sending-interrupt#focus=Comments-27-6454622.0-0